# Five nights at Freddy's blue animatronic

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

What is the big blue animatronic's name in cam 8? I got jumpscared.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a screenshot or similar things? From my experience, the blue animatronic that can jumpscare you is either Bonnie or Toy Bonnie. Toy Bonnie has a much brighter blue color, while Bonnie is darker.

You may want to check [Bonnie's jumpscare](http://freddy-fazbears-pizza.wikia.com/wiki/Bonnie?file=Bonnie_blarg.gif) or [Toy Bonnie's jumpscare](http://freddy-fazbears-pizza.wikia.com/wiki/Toy_Bonnie?file=Output_ALnTij.gif).

Source: FNAF wiki + my experience

Comment: Looks like it would be Old Bonnie, the gif you linked to is of fnaf 1 bonnie...

Answer (score -1):

The ''blue thing'' is Bonnie or  Toy Bonnie. In the 2nd game, Bonnie is known as W. Bonnie.